# Passing parameters correctly to a Linux binary that is run with Qt's QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

I have a binary that I compiled and which I run on the terminal using : 
`./pnrxms dataset-bc.arff 0.1 0.9` where pnrxms is the binary name and dataset-bc.arff, 0.1, 0.9 are the three parameters the program requires.

To do the same from inside Qt, I used the following code:

```
QProcess sh;
sh.start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "/home/r/l33t/Qt_RoughWork/source/menuandtoolbar/pnrxms dataset-bc.arff 0.1 0.9");

sh.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output = sh.readAll();
ui->textBrowser->setText(output);
```

But this did not work. It DID start the program but failed to fetch the arguments. The program ran how it runs without any parameters.

So, then I tried this second way:

```
QProcess sh;

sh.start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "/home/r/l33t/Qt_RoughWork/source/menuandtoolbar/pnrxms" <<"dataset-bc.arff"<<"0.1"<<"0.9");

sh.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output = sh.readAll();
ui->textBrowser->setText(output);
```

This time however, nothing happened. That is, the program did not run at all.

So, my question is, How do I correctly pass my arguments to my program while it is being run by QProcess.

Comment: have you tried running instead the program `int main(int c, char **v) { while (*v) puts(*v++); return 0; }`?

Comment: I think he is saying have the child process print out what arguments it sees, so that you can know what arguments are being passed (and thus whether or not you are passing the arguments you think you are passing, or not)

Comment: Yes, I got it. Will try it once i go back home again :) thanks @jthill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works :

```
sh.start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "/home/r/l33t/Qt_RoughWork/source/menuandtoolbar/pnrxms" dataset-bc.arff 0.1 0.9");
```